# mySQL DELIMITER throwing 1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS eventsNearMe$$

CREATE PROCEDURE eventsNearMe(IN inIP VARCHAR(16))
BEGIN

DECLARE ipLAT FLOAT;
DECLARE ipLONG FLOAT;

SELECT iplocationdb_location.latitude, iplocationdb_location.longitude
 INTO ipLAT, ipLONG
 FROM `iplocationdb_ip`
 LEFT JOIN iplocationdb_location ON iplocationdb_location.id=iplocationdb_ip.location_id
 WHERE iplocationdb_ip.prefix=(INET_ATON(inIP)>>24)
 AND INET_ATON(inIP) BETWEEN iplocationdb_ip.start_ip AND iplocationdb_ip.end_ip LIMIT 1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempEVENTS
SELECT `eid`,(((acos(sin((ipLAT*pi()/180)) * sin((`lat`*pi()/180))+cos((ipLAT*pi()/180)) * cos((`lat`*pi()/180)) * cos(((ipLONG- `long`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) as d FROM `mke_events` HAVING `d` <= 10 LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM tempEVENTS;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tempEVENTS;
END 
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The above code should, by my understanding, create a quick little sp to get events near a given ip address.  However through all my searching I haven't found a satisfactory reason for it to be throwing 1064 on DELIMITER (line 1).
Even if I have JUST:

```
DELIMITER $$
SELECT * FROM iplocationdb_location;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It still fires 1064.  mySQL version 5.0.77.

NOTE: I DO have my space between DELIMITER and the delimiting string.
NOTE2:  I am using heidiSQL to run this script, which should be tantamount to running it from the command line by my understanding.

Comment: I think the last line should be `DELIMITER ; $$`

Comment: UPDATE:  i passed the sql file to someone else and he got it to create the SP.  Weird right?

Comment: ANOTHER UPDATE:  Apparently there was an issue with the permissions.  Not sure why it was coming through as a syntax error, but it seems fine now.

Comment: How are you inserting that code? Are you using PHP? Probably you should remove DELIMITER, and replace all $$ with ;

Answer (score 1):

I also was getting spurious DELIMITER-related syntax errors, with command-line mysql but not with HeidiSQL, due to extra trailing whitespace (tab characters) on the DELIMITER line. Eg:

```
DELIMITER ;<TAB><TAB>
```

Removing the trailing whitespace fixed it (your comment about whitespace tipped me off, thank you.)